# How to put placeholder in Django date range filter

Tags: python, django, date

I am using Django filters to search by giving date range in my application.

```
class AdvancedSearchListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    received = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(label='Received Date Range')

    class Meta:
        model = Container
        fields = ['received']
```

So then this filter will create where I am searching To and From date range.SO in that I want to put a place holder to show the Date format like 'yyyy/mm/dd'.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can  assign a placeholder like it is done with an ordinary django form

```
class AdvancedSearchInboxFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    received = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(
        label='Received Date Range',
        widget=django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'yyyy/mm/dd'}))

    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ['received']
```

Comment: I have tried as u suggested..It showing me an error:AttributeError: 'AdvancedSearchInboxFilter' object has no attribute 'fields'.

Comment: Again throwing an error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DateInput'                                                                                                     I only did import :from django.forms import forms and I am using Django's latest 1.9 version,python 3.4

Comment: Only import `from django import forms`

Comment: Hey Its working but as I am using DateFromToRangeFilter,earlier i was showing two search boxes for the  To and From functionality.now only one search box is there with placeholder.

Comment: Try using `django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget()` instead of `forms.DateInput()`

Comment: Another error: TypeError: Meta.fields contains a field that isn't defined on this FilterSet .                                                                                             I did import : from django_filters import widgets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107850/discussion-between-v1k45-and-sneha-shinde).

Comment: Its working now using django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget() instead of forms.DateInput().Thanks.