# Adding placeholder to form in Django when using django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am developing a web application which displays an html table using django-tables2 and which allows filtering this table using django-filter.
In my html template I can simply put `{% filter.form %}` and I am getting a full form for filtering my table which I think is really great and easy.

However, I would like to add placeholders to this form which would be in plane html (using Bootstrap4) something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
             placeholder="ENTER PLACEHOLDER HERE" name="email">
            </div>
       </form>
    </div>
```

(example taken form here:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_basic&stacked=h and edited)

How can I add a placeholder when working with django-filters and all I am doing is adding `% filter.form %}` to my template?

**Edit:**
My question was half complete. The answer given by @schwobaseggl works great for most filters. However, when having a `RangeFilter` and two fields show up (one for the max value and one for the min value) how to set two *separate* placeholders? One can put the *same* placeholder into both fields as explained here: [How to put placeholder in Django date range filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329019/how-to-put-placeholder-in-django-date-range-filter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define your `Filter`, provide the `placeholder` attribute via the [`attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) kwarg of the `widget` constructor:

```
# ...
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput, ...

class FooFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    bar = filters.CharFilter(..., widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'baz'}))
```

Comment: Great that works for me with ``CharFilters`` and alike, thanks. How about ``RangeFilter`` which lead to two input fields on the website? When I pass it like this only one field stays and the second disappears. However, I would like to have both and write something like "min" into the 1st and "max" into the "2nd".

Comment: @ALA You have to pick the appropriate widget for the filter type, see https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/widgets.html#rangewidget. I don't know how you would go about two different placeholders though. You might have to look at the source/template code of the widget.

Comment: I have found this post which explains how to put a placeholder for a ``RangeFilter``: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329019/how-to-put-placeholder-in-django-date-range-filter. However it puts the same placeholder for both fields. The missing piece would still be how to set in the min field e.g. a "min" placeholder and in the max field a "max" placeholder

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput

class BikesFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    sell_price = django_filters.NumberFilter()
    sell_price__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='sell_price', lookup_expr 
    ='gte', label='sell price min', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'min'}))
    sell_price__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='sell_price', lookup_expr 
    = 'lte', label='sell price max', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'max'}))

   class Meta:
    model = Bike
    fields = (
               'sell_price'
             )
```

[image]